# Ultrafilters and weakly partition regular families

Tags: elementary-set-theory, filters, set-partition

I am asked to prove that if a family $\mathcal{A}$ of subsets of X is $\textit{weakly partition regular}$, then it contains an ultrafilter.

The definition of "weakly partition regular" I'm working with is "a family $\mathcal{A}$ such that for every partition $X = C_1 \sqcup ... \sqcup C_r $ ($r$ might vary)  of the entire set there exists an $i$ such that $C_i \in \mathcal{A}$.

The hint I am given is to consider the family $\{ A \mid A^c \notin \mathcal{A}\}$.

I really can't do it and I am starting to think that some hypotheses might be missing.

As an alternative attempt to solve it I'm wondering if a minimal weakly partition regular family must be an ultrafilter (I believe I've proven the converse).

Comment: Prove that $\{A|A^c\notin\mathcal A\}$ has the finite intersection property. Any ultrafilter extending it will be included in $\mathcal A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, there is a missing assumption that $\mathcal{A}$ is closed upwards (which, from what I know, is usually part of the definition of weakly partition regular). Assuming that:

An ultrafilter (on $X$) is a filter such that $B∈\mathcal{F}⇔X\setminus B∉\mathcal{F}$.

So given $C=\{ A \mid X\setminus A \notin \mathcal{A}\}$ we can see:

Let $A,B∈C$ then $A\cap B∪(X \setminus A)∪((X\setminus B)\cap A)=X⇒ A\cap B\in \mathcal{A}\quad(*)$

This follows from the fact that $(X\setminus B)∩ A∈\mathcal{A}⇒X\setminus B∈\mathcal{A}$. Similar deconstruction of $X$ using any finite number of $A_i∈C$ will also work.

Let's assume that $∅∉\mathcal{A}$(as it is trivial if it is), then $(*)$ proves that $C$ has the finite intersection property. Extending $C$ into a filter $C⊆\mathcal{F}_C⊆\mathcal{A}$ can be easily done by noting that $\mathcal{A}$ is closed by supset, so every supset of finite intersection of elements of $C$ is in $\mathcal{A}$.

Extend $\mathcal{F}_C$ into $\mathcal{U}$ an ultrafilter,  assume that $B∈\mathcal{U}$ but $B∉\mathcal{A}$, then by definition $X\setminus B∈C⊆\mathcal{F}_C⊆\mathcal{U}$

---

Unfortunately I don't have any counter examples in mind that shows that the extra assumption is necessary

---

<strike>As an alternative attempt to solve it I'm wondering if a minimal weakly partition regular family must be an ultrafilter (I believe I've proven the converse).</strike>

Also note that that if $\mathcal{A}$ is weakly partition regular, then $\mathcal{A}∪\{∅\}$ is also weakly partition regular, so this is wrong

Sorry, I didn't notice the "minimal" part.

Comment: 1) When you write that $A\cap B∪(X \setminus A)∪(X\setminus B)=X \Rightarrow A\cap B\in C\quad (*)$  you seem to imply that the union on the left is a partition, but this is true only if $X \setminus A$ and $X\setminus B$ are disjoint, i.e. $A \cup B = X$, and I don't see why that should be the case.

Comment: 2) I can't see why the filter $\mathcal{F}$ has also the ultrafilter property on complements.

Comment: 3) If $ \mathcal{A}$ is weakly partition regular, then $\mathcal{A} \cup \{ \emptyset \}$ is not minimal, so I can't understand why that should be a counterexample to my guess.

Comment: @MatteoCasarosa Sorry, I fixed my answer in regard to 1 and 2, about 3 - I didn't notice the word minimal